# Go Neural Network - Learning then De-Learning

Tags: go, neural-network, backpropagation

I have been working on a neural network for the classic MNIST Digit data set. The code was directly inspired and has many conversions from Michael Nielsen's first network.py file used in his book: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html. I have gotten it to were it can produce an accuracy of about 80% for one epoch.

**What happens is that for the first epoch the accuracy is very low ~around 20%, then in the next 3-4 epochs get to 80% then from there slowly start decreasing in accuracy (after 50 epochs it was about 4683 / 10000 with a batch size of 50 and a learning rate of 0.5).** The problem has to do with backpropagation as I've narrowed it down and there are some problems. Here's the direct code for the backprop algorithm I am running:

```
func (nn *network) backprop(x *mnist.Image, y mnist.Label) ([]*mat.Dense, []*mat.Dense) {
    //Defines nabla_b adn nabla_w and populates them with 0s
    nabla_b := make([]*mat.Dense, len(nn.biases))
    for i := range nn.biases {
        nabla_b[i] = mat.NewDense(nn.biases[i].RawMatrix().Rows, 1, nil)

    }
    nabla_w := make([]*mat.Dense, len(nn.weights))
    for i := range nn.weights {
        nabla_w[i] = mat.NewDense(nn.weights[i].RawMatrix().Rows, nn.weights[i].RawMatrix().Cols, nil)

    }
    //Creates a usuable input matrix with each row being a pixel with a a value at column 0 pretaining to the color value from 0 - 255
    a := mat.NewDense(len(x), 1, nil)
    for i := 0; i < len(x); i++ {
        val := float64(x[i])
        a.Set(i, 0, val/255)
    }
    //Creates lists of *mat.Denses for storing z matrices and activation matrices
    zs := make([]*mat.Dense, nn.numLayers-1)
    activations := make([]*mat.Dense, nn.numLayers)
    //Stores input in activations at 0
    activations[0] = a
    //Feedforwards stroing zs and activations
    for i := 0; i < len(nn.weights); i++ {
        weights := nn.weights[i]
        biases := nn.biases[i]
        z := mat.NewDense(weights.RawMatrix().Rows, a.RawMatrix().Cols, nil)

        z.Mul(weights, a)
        z.Add(z, biases)

        zs[i] = z
        applySigmoid := func(_, _ int, v float64) float64 {
            return sigmoid(v)
        }
        z.Apply(applySigmoid, z)
        a = z
        activations[i+1] = a
    }
    //Starts backpropagation by setting delta equal to the cost_derivative using the last layer of activations and label
    delta := nn.cost_derivative(activations[len(activations)-1], y)
    //Multiplies each value in the matrix by the corresponding sigmoidPrime value in the zs matrix at the last layer
    for i := 0; i < delta.RawMatrix().Rows; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < delta.RawMatrix().Cols; j++ {
            delta.Set(i, j, delta.At(i, j)*sigmoidPrime(zs[len(zs)-1].At(i, j)))
        }
    }
    //Sets the outputs last layers - bias to delta and weights to delta * last layer of activations transposed
    nabla_b[len(nabla_b)-1] = delta
    nabla_w[len(nabla_w)-1].Mul(delta, activations[len(activations)-1].T())

    //For the number of layers back propagates
    for l := 2; l < nn.numLayers; l++ {
        z := zs[len(zs)-l]
        temp := z
        applySigmoidPrime := func(_, _ int, v float64) float64 {
            return sigmoidPrime(v)
        }
        //Applies sigmoidPrime to the z matrix stored in temp
        temp.Apply(applySigmoidPrime, z)
        //Sets delta to weights transposed * delta
        delta.Mul(nn.weights[len(nn.weights)-l+1].T(), delta)
        //Multiples the elements by the sigmoidPrime elements of the z matrix
        delta.MulElem(delta, temp)
        //Sets the outputs similarly

        nabla_b[len(nabla_b)-l] = delta
        nabla_w[len(nabla_w)-l].Mul(delta, activations[len(activations)-l-1].T())
    }
    return nabla_b, nabla_w
}
```

And here is the github repository that contains the actual file(s):
https://github.com/nhrobertson/GoDigitRecSimpleNN/tree/GoDigitRecognitionSimpleNN

Some key pointer that I have found during some trial and error debugging:
`nabla_w[len(nabla_w)-1].Mul(delta, activations[len(activations)-1].T())` 
should be
`nabla_w[len(nabla_w)-1].Mul(delta, activations[len(activations)-2].T())` 
However when making that adjustment, the accuracy falls low (about 0.9%). I've discovered that this is most likely due to the `activations[len(activations)-2]` to very small values. This is due to the sigmoid function in the feedforward part of the backprop algorithm. The sigmoid is working with rather large numbers which inturn produces extremely small adjustments which don't help with learning at all.

That is the main problem that I have narrowed down. I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now. I have also tried forcefully scaling the large numbers to no avail.  I didn't really no where else to ask this question so I came to the great community at stackoverflow. I am currently preparing to move on from this problem and start a new version on my own but, if you have the time and want to look at this problem it would be much appreciated!